# Lightbox event on ajax loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to use jQuery for the first time. I have some images that are loaded via an ajax call (not jQuery related). The page is made the way that if you refresh the page, the images loaded, stay.

I found this code somewhere else:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".svg_chart").click(function(){
    var address = $(this).attr("src");
    address = address.replace(\'height=80\', \'height=300\');
    $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#lightbox").attr("src",address);
});
$("#lightbox").click(function(){
    $("#popup").fadeOut("fast");
});
});

    <div id="popup">
        <div id="center">
            <img id="lightbox" src="images/blank.jpg" >
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The code works fine on images already loaded when the page is loaded, but not on images fetched on the fly with Ajax, although they get the same class added. I guess it is because the doc.ready function only knows about content, after the initial page has loaded.
What can I do to make jQuery know about new content being added?

Comment: you can replace "click" function by "live" or preferably "on" functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping jQuery for this. It's overkill and doesn't work!

```
<img id="svg_1" class="svg_chart" style="float: left" width="49%" ondblclick="expand_me(this.id)" alt="" />

<div id="popup">
</div>
<div id="center">
    <img onclick="expand_me(true)" id="lightbox" src="images/blank.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- // --><![CDATA[
function expand_me(el)
{
    if (el !== true)
    {
        link = document.getElementById(el).src;
        link = link.replace(\'height=80\', \'height=300\');
        document.getElementById(\'popup\').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(\'center\').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(\'lightbox\').src = link;
     } 
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(\'popup\').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(\'center\').style.display = "none";
    }
}
// ]]></script>
```

The css part:

```
#popup
{
    background:#000000;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#center
{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 6% auto;
    display: none;
}
#lightbox
{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```